# angular xeditable typeahead show all items by default when typeahead is empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, x-editable

Using angularjs xeditable typeahead, how do we show all items by default when typeahead is empty.

Current example of the angularjs xeditable typeahead is at http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#typeahead

Answer (score 1):

I got a working solution by changing some code in ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js.
So there are no differences in the typeahead html markup.

You can have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/CutBFE?p=preview

To use this fix, use the ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js from the Plunk.
To see my changes, open ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js from the Plunk and search for 'ahneo'.

```
 1. //minimal no of characters that needs to be entered before typeahead
    kicks-in
    // ahneo :: before
    //var minSearch = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadMinLength) || 1;
    // ahneo :: after (changed minimal no of characters to 0 by default)
    var minSearch = originalScope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadMinLength) || 0;
 2. // ahneo :: new (set input value to empty string if it contains " " string value)
    if (inputValue === ' ') {
        inputValue = '';
        modelCtrl.$setViewValue('');
    }  
 3. // ahneo :: before
    //if (inputValue && inputValue.length >= minSearch) {
    // ahneo :: after (add new condition to get matches for min search = 0)
    if (minSearch === 0 || inputValue && inputValue.length >= minSearch) {
 4. // ahneo :: new (bind element to focus event to trigger modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift method)
    element.bind('focus', function (evt) {
        if (modelCtrl.$viewValue === '') {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(' ');
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps